# Issue facing for xcode-ui-testing in XCode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-ui-automation, swift3.2

UI Test for an ios-app, developed in XCode 8 and swift 3.2.

Facing problem to deal with ScrollViews, collectionViews after upgrade XCode to 9

I can tap and access the Buttons, StaticTexts, TextFields elements.
But I can not tap or access the collectionviews, scrollviews, tableviews elements on XCode9 and Swift 3.2.

Suppose in the previous XCode version (i.e, XCode 8.3) I used the code `app.collectionViews.collectionViews.cells.images.element(boundBy: 0).tap()`
to tap on Home page(collectionViews). But this code is not working in XCode 9.

I tried to get the exact element using uitest recording feature.
By using recording I got the code -

```
app.collectionViews.otherElements.containing(.textField, identifier:"StoryboardTitleTextField").children(matching: .collectionView).element.tap().
```

But this code isn't working too. So how can I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently i also faced the similar type of issue after upgrading my project(Swift 3.2) into XCode 9.

The issue is

```
 app.collectionViews.collectionViews.cells.images.element(boundBy: 0).isHittable is returning false.
```

Thats why default **tap()** method is not working for hierarchical elements.

I just did the below procedure and that worked fine.

**Step 1**: Create an extension like below

```
extension XCUIElement {
func tryClick() {
    if self.isHittable {
        self.tap()
    }
    else {
        let coordinate: XCUICoordinate = self.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx:0.5, dy:0.5))
        coordinate.doubleTap()
        //coordinate.press(forDuration: 0.5)
    }
  }
}
```

**Step 2:** click on the element using the instance method created above instead of using direct tap() method.

```
app.collectionViews.collectionViews.cells.images.element(boundBy: 0).tryClick()
```

**Note:** try using

```
CGVector(dx:0.5, dy:0.5) or CGVector(dx:0.0, dy:0.0)
```

Hope it will solve your issue. It worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Thanks mahmud. Excellent job you have done. It is also working for me. Can you tell me what does `CGVector(dx:0.5, dy:0.5)` do here in the extension method.

Comment: @AliAzam   It is the co-ordinate  x , y location you want to tap on that element. Please let me know if it  solved your issue or not.